# I have a column how can i know the first visible item and last visible item jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a column, and I want to know which is the first visible item and the last visible item. Although it is behaving like a lazycolumn, but i cannot use a lazycolumn cause my app will crash cause it's attached to custom layout using the same scroll state. So it is a sidebar containing the hours for 7 days.

```
@Composable
fun ScheduleSidebar(
    hourHeight: Dp,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    label: @Composable (time: LocalTime) -> Unit = { HourLabel(time = it) },
  
) {
    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        val startTime = LocalTime.MIN
        repeat(7) { day ->
            repeat(24) { hour ->
                Box(modifier = Modifier.height(hourHeight)) {
                    label(startTime.plusHours(hour.toLong()))
                }
            }
         
        }

    }
}
```

Hour Label:

```
@Composable
fun HourLabel(
    time: LocalTime,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Text(
        text = time,
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .padding(4.dp)
    )
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should ask a question about this "my app will crash cause it's attached to custom layout using the same scroll state". LazyColumn is the way to go here.

Comment: @Jorn but how can i scroll the custom layout and lazy column together

Answer (score 0):

###### This is only an example to help you understand how to achieve your goal. I've explained each column you can see and read.

```kotlin
    // Count of repeat
    val repeatCount = 7
    val startCountFrom = 1 // default = 0
    /*
    * Creates a list of repeated numbers from 1 to [repeatCount].
    * repeatCount The number of times the list should be repeated.
    */
    val repeatedList = List((startCountFrom..repeatCount).toList().size) { index -> index + 1 }

    Column {
        /* Iterates over each element in the [repeatedList] and performs the given action on each element. */
        repeatedList.forEach { number ->
            /* Determines if the current [number] is the first element in the [repeatedList]. */
            val first = repeatedList.first() == number
            /* Determines if the current [number] is the last element in the [repeatedList]. */
            val last = repeatedList.last() == number

            /* Displays a text element with the value of [number] and an additional label if it's the first or last element.*/
            if (first) {
                Text(text = "$number [FIRST]")
            } else if (last) {
                Text(text = "$number [LAST]")
            } else {
                Text(text = number.toString())
            }
        }
    }
```

###### Try to use **LazyColum** instead of **Column**

-Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should you use LazyColumn for your approach and also inside lazycolumn you can use itemsIndex and on the basis of index you can determine first and last item of the list.

```
 LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
    itemsIndexed(state.notes){index,note ->
     if(index == 0){
    // first item
    // do your stuff
                  }
     if(index == (state.notes.size-1)){
      // last item
      // do your stuff
     }  
  }
}
```